# AG Grid Pagination with Infinite Scrolling

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm implementing ag-grid on angular 4 and having issues with the server side pagination.

Is there a way to go to a particular page on grid ready event while implementing the Pagination with Infinite Scrolling?

Comment: you meant to say you want to reach at particular scroll position. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

When you say particular page with infinite scrolling, I assume you want to reach at particular scroll position.

Let say, at once, you are fetching 20 records from server (you `getRows` method is also fetching the same number of records), and you want to `50th` record when the grid is loaded.

Follow below steps.

```
// #1  initialize grid with empty array, getRows will fetch the records
let dataSource = {
  rowCount: null,
  getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => this.getRows(params, [])
};
this.gridApi.setDatasource(dataSource);


// #2.
private getRows(params: IGetRowsParams, data: any) {
    this.yourSvc.getRows(serverParams, params.startRow)
        .subscribe((result: any[]) => {

             params.successCallback(result, null);

             // #3. keep a flag just to make sure its done for the first time only
             if(this.isFirstTime) {
                this.gridApi.ensureColumnVisible(0);
                this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(50);
                this.gridApi.setFocusedCell(50, 0, null);

                this.isFirstLoad = false;
             }
        });
}
```